# android - passing variable from intent extra to ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-intent

Android newcomer here. I'm trying to setup an activity to display a selected image.  The foundation of this code is from the Hello, Android 3rd edition (Pragmatic Programmer) that I have attempted to modify.

Basically, I want to be able to click a button in one activity, and have that start another activity that changes the layout to display the image associated with that button.  I have several buttons, and would like each button to cause a different image to be displayed.

**files (simplified code by removing pic3-...):**

main.xml : layout for two buttons (pic1 and pic2)

Main.java : contains onclicklisteners for buttons - intents w/ extras (filename for image)

Viewer.java : default created by eclipse, purpose is to set new layout  setContentView(R.layout.viewer);

viewer.xml : layout for ImageView

I have gotten strings stored in strings.xml to work (I create a string in eclipse with a value of @drawable/pic1 and give it a name of imagename so I can call @string/imagename for the src of ImageView in viewer.xml).

However, I have learned from searching and reading on this forum that I cannot change strings.xml values from within an activity (my original idea was to have a couple lines of code in Viewer.java that would change the imagename string to whatever was passed by the Intent extras.

I found this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523384/android-pass-string-from-activity-to-layout) where someone was trying to do a similar thing with a TextView, but I've tried that route and I keep getting syntax errors on those lines.

I'm really stuck. Any ideas?
Thanks!

### main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);


// click listeners
View pic1Button = findViewById(R.id.pic1_button);
pic1Button.setOnClickListener(this);
View pic2Button = findViewById(R.id.pic2_button);
pic2Button.setOnClickListener(this);

}

// ...
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {

   case R.id.pic1_button:
      Intent l = new Intent(this, Viewer.class);
      l.putExtra("imagefilename", "pic1filename");
      startActivity(l);
      break;

   case R.id.pic2_button:
      Intent i = new Intent(this, Viewer.class);
      i.putExtra("imagefilename", "pic2filename");
      startActivity(i);
      break;

}
}
}
```

### viewer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:src='@string/imagename'
      android:scaleType="matrix">
   </ImageView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: android:src='@string/imagename' needs to be android:src="@drawable/imagename" Note the double quotes and the change in type. In addition, you may also need to remove imagename from strings.xml, and place a + in front of drawable/imagename. In other words the final result may look like android:src="+@drawable/imagename" That being said, a couple of questions remain. Where are your images going to be located? And what's in your Viewer.java file?

Comment: Indeed, Stephan it right, my answer corrects that + I have assumed your images will be located to res/drawable as png files. My solution is based on the use of `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_pic);`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but from my understanding you could achieve that using the following code.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.stackoverflow.biowi"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
     <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:name="Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="Viewer" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Main.java:

```
package com.stackoverflow.biowi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // click listeners
        View pic1Button = findViewById(R.id.pic1_button);
        pic1Button.setOnClickListener(this);
        View pic2Button = findViewById(R.id.pic2_button);
        pic2Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, Viewer.class);

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.pic1_button:
            i.putExtra("imagefilename", "pic1filename");
            break;
        case R.id.pic2_button:
            i.putExtra("imagefilename", "pic2filename");
            break;
         }
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Viewer.java:

```
package com.stackoverflow.biowi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Viewer extends Activity
{

    /** To be documented. */
    private Bitmap mImage1;
    /** To be documented. */
    private Bitmap mImage2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewer);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String imageName = bundle.getString("imagefilename");


        // click listeners
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        mImage1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1);
        mImage2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic2);

        if(imageName.matches("pic1filename")) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mImage1);
        } else if (imageName.matches("pic2filename")) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mImage2);
        }
    }

}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              >
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Hello World, Main"
      />
  <Button android:id="@+id/pic1_button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
  <Button android:id="@+id/pic2_button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

viewer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:src='@drawable/pingouin'
             android:scaleType="matrix">
  </ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

With pic1.png, pic2.png and pingouin.png in res/drawable…

Comment: @biowi Any feedbacks on the proposed solution? Is this what do you wanted to achieve, etc.?

Comment: sorry for the delay. I've been trying to implement your code in the package.  I guess I didn't fully explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to make a basic guide application. It has several layouts (basically collections of buttons). Each layout has a button or two that is associated with an image.  I have an activity that I got from the pragmatic programmer book that takes an image on a layout and implements pinch zoom. The code was written for a single image.  What I want to do is keep the viewer as an activity, and depending on which button is pressed, load a different image. I'd like to code something that I can just change the intent, and not have to code the filename into two different places. Is this possible?

Comment: Example: 4 buttons on layout (button1-button3,nextbutton). click on button1 and image1 is displayed. click on button 2 and image2 is displayed. or click on nextbutton and layout2 is displayed (with button5-button9). click on button 5 and image5 is displayed. I'd like to be able to put the filename in the OnClick intent and not have to add code anywhere else if I add more buttons and images.

Comment: Please upate your question with the Viewer class code to see what could be done.